Is it possible to dynamically set the template string?
I would like to configure outside of my program a template string, and then apply it at runtime:
my_string = "hello {country}" # ← this string would be read in from an external configuration file
country = "France"
print(f%%my_string%%) # ← the place where the magic happens

Is this possible or is there a proper way to do this?

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method?

@jonrsharpe ahhh, .format() - I forgot about that one (after having left aside Python for an extended time). Thanks!

You could do it like this:
my_string.format(country=country)

Just take a look at str.format() method.

Yes, create a file, for example example.txt. Use the open() method to open the file, and then use the readline() to read the first line into a string.
Then write something like:
with open('example.txt') as f1:
country = "France"
print(f1.readline().replace('{country}', country))

